# Simplifying expression with SymPy by specifying ranges

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I would like to simplify an expression with cases/branches by specifying the range of my `Idx` object. Consider the following example:

```py
import sympy as sym

i = sym.Idx("i")
j = sym.Idx("j")
N = sym.Symbol("N", integer=True)
expr = sym.Sum(sym.KroneckerDelta(i, j), (i, 1, N))
expr.doit()
```

This outputs:

[image]

I tried to use `refine` together with `Q`, which I would expect to work by reading the documentation. But it does not work:

```py
sym.refine(expr.doit(), sym.Q.positive_definite(j))
```

This outputs the same as before. It does not simplify the first case condition to N >= j, as I expected.
How to incorporate such conditions/assumptions when simplifying an expression?

Answer (score 0):

You can put bounds on the indices:

```
In [4]: import sympy as sym
   ...: 
   ...: N = symbols('N')
   ...: i = sym.Idx("i", (1, N))
   ...: j = sym.Idx("j", (1, N))
   ...: expr = sym.Sum(sym.KroneckerDelta(i, j), (i, 1, N))
   ...: expr.doit()
Out[4]: 
⎧1  for N ≥ j
⎨            
⎩0  otherwise
```

Comment: Shouldn't the result be simply 1? It is impossible to have j > N with the bounds that you chose.

Comment: Furthermore, if I do this my indices get altered. Instead of printing N >= j as you wrote, my interpreter displays N >= j_1...N.